# Thread Priority on application using java

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee

Can you help me in two problem :

A. We have a table on which read and write operation happens simultaneously.  Write happens very vastly so read is very slow - sometimes my web application does not come up due to heavy write operation on this table. How could i handle such scenario. Write happens through different Java application while read happens through our web application, so web application become very slow. Any idea?

B. Write happens to this table happens through 200 threads, these thread take connection from connection pool and write into the table and this application run 24 by 7. is the thread priority is having issue and stopping read operation from web application.

C. Can we have master- master replication for that table only- so write happens in one table and write happens in other table and every two minute data migrates from one table to other table?

Please suggest me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check connection pool size - maybe it's too small and your threads waste time waiting for connection from pool.
2. Check your database settings, if you just running it with out-of-the-box params there maybe a good space for improvements.
3. You probably need some kind of event-driven system - when vehicle sends data DB is not updated, but a message is added to some queue (e.g. JMS). Your app then caches data on startup, and updates both cache and  database upon receiving this message. The key thing is that the only component that interacts with DB is your app, and data changed only when you receive event - so you don't need to query DB to read the data, plus you may do updates in the background using only few threads, etc. There are quite good open-source messaging systems (e.g. Apache Active MQ) and caching libraries (e.g. EH Cache), so you can built reasonably perfomant and fault-tolerant system with not too much effort.
4. I guess introducing messaging will be a serious reengineering, so to solve your immediate problem replication might be the best solution - merge data from the updateable table to another one every 2 minutes, and the tracker will read that another table; obviously works well if you only read the data in the web-app, and not update them, otherwise you need to put a lot of effort to keep 2 tables in sync. A variation of that is batching - data from vehicle are iserted into intermediate table, and then every 2 minutes  transferred into main table from which reader queries them; intermediate table is cleaned after transfer.

Comment: I have two standalone application- One application write data into DB after reading packet from HornetQ and this is running on different server but only write the data to DB server which is also standalone. We have one standalone web application which reads data from the same table where my other application writes. so we have two application which query the same table to DB and both application running on different server and Database is also in different server. I am already using HornetQ messaging system but this JMS system stores incoming packets coming from devices. Suggest me

Comment: Hm, so why 2 apps then? I would merge them into one, and stored data in Java cache so that readers won't go into DB. Even with 2 apps - why 200 writers? You may benefit from throttling, using fewer threads and bigger batches. The corner case is to have 1 thread running  loop like that: fetch all the messages, write them in 1 JDBC batch, sleep for a minute, repeat forever; 1 thread, 1 transaction every  minute, plenty of time for readers to run their queries.

Comment: I did not get this logic, could you please explain me completely. thanks

Comment: @Anand - this is quite simple; you make a method that fetches from the queue using `receiveNoWait()` unless next message is null, or some limit is reached; while fetching you add each message to JDBC batch.
Then you execute the whole batch and commit DB and JMS. Then you implement a background thread that does all the above in a endless loop, sleeping for some time - e.g. a minute between iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Could you please help me two do update batch in every five minutes - I will create one intermediate table - which will dump in every five minute to the actual table and intermediate table will get clean- can you tell me how should i do that or any link where i can get the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The one true way to solve this is to use a queue of write events and to stop the writing periodically so that the reader has a chance.

1. Create a queue for incoming write updates
2. Create an atomicXXX (see java.util.concurrency) to use as a lock
3. Create a thread pool to read from the queue and execute the updates when the lock is unset
4. Use javax.swing.Timer to periodically set the lock and read the table data.

Comment: In my scenario - i can not do that this - since i need to show our users to the live detail of their vehicle, we have installed 10,000 GPS devices on vehicles and each device send data every 2 minutes so our users wants to track all vehicle every two minutes via web application interface. so we need to do read and write operation same time. Please suggest.

Comment: If your timer is set to 30 or 50 ms it will appear virtually instantly

Comment: In this case you need to either get personal help thru a teacher or a consultant, or put aside your project for a while and get some practice with swing & doing animations / updating gui using simple cases

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything too complicated try this perhaps:

1) Don't use Thread priorities, they are rarely what you want.

2) Set up your own priority scheme, perhaps simply by having a (priority) queue for both reads  and writes where reads are prioritized. That is: add read and write requests to a single queue and have them block or be notified of the result.

3) check your database features to optimize write heavy tables

Comment: we can not have read and write operation together, We have one application which does write to the DB and another application which do read to the DB. Both are standalone tomcat application- so how can i build a priority queue to maintain both read and write, need suggestion

Comment: You can either let of of the apps go through the other or introduce a third.

Comment: Have you checked your database table/row locking settings. For example in MySql I think some (most?) tables default to table locking which is quite bad if you have lots of writes. Locking the entire table... see for example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html

Comment: is it possible to to master-slave replication for only one table. I have a Database with 100 table, but i am interested in only one table, is it possible